# Saving a list of points into a text file

Tags: java, tiles, terrain, side-scroller, perlin-noise

I recently posted a question about this, but was not really sure where to go. I've gotten some progress, and have generated some simple noise here:

http://pastie.org/5408655

That works well enough for me, but I would really like to be able to save the points into an ascii text file. currently it's formatted so that something like this:

11111111

11111111

11111111

11111111

would create a square. I need to save in this format with the points(and lines connecting them) generated in the method above.

Essentially, I need to write the array of points created in the first example to a text file formatted like the second example.
EDIT: 
I ended up using serialization. This method makes it un-editable, but works for my purposes, I can really have good terrain generation now. here's my code: http://pastie.org/5455624 Everything is working excellently. Thanks to all those who helped

Comment: Your question, if I'm interpreting it correctly, is: "how do I write a text file from Java?"  Is that correct?

Comment: No, not exactly. I need to write an array of points into a text file in the format used in my example. Edited for clarity.

Comment: How do your points look like then? I mean, do you have Java classes for them? Maybe a bit code would help.

Comment: What do you mean? I put the code in the post. The class "Point" is built in to java.

Comment: Paste your solution as an answer and accept it. Maybe someone can make use of it later.

Comment: Did that, but it was pretty much the same answer so i removed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could consider `Serialization`

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm

Advantages

1. Hides your values
2. Easier to save/load

Disadvantages

1. Values can not be modified in text editor.